# Cherry-pick: from two URLs with same file on different CDNs, load whichever is in cache

Tags: service-worker, cdn, progressive-web-apps

I have a web app that wants to load bootstrap.min.js

It's on these two CDN's (among others):

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js

The odds of a cache hit from some other app using these CDN's is relatively high.

How can I tell the browser to check if they are cached and load from browser cache?

Can a service worker do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there are some privacy/security restrictions in place that attempt that make it difficult to determine, using JavaScript, whether a third-party URL is present in the browser's cache.

Adding a service worker into the mix will not get around those restrictions.

It's possible to use the Fetch API to create a `Request` with a [`mode` of `'only-if-cached'`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-cache-mode), which will behave more or less in the way you describe, but that will only work if the request's `mode` is `'same-origin'`. In other words, only if the `Request` is for a first-party URL, not a third-party CDN URL as in your example.